# Arduino Uno Stepper Motor Issues

Tags: c++, arduino

I am working with a stepper motor hooked up to pins 9, 10, 11, and 12 on an Arduino Uno. In order to rotate the stepper motor, I wrote a helper method. This particular stepper motor rotates 1.8 degrees per step. The method is:

```
void rotateStepperBy(float deg) {
  int steps = deg / 1.8;
  motor.step(steps);
}
```

The method works fine for small degree measures, but behaves in unexpected ways (under rotating, rotating back and forth) if I give it larger degree measures like 45 and 90. Here's an example I was trying:

```
#include <Stepper.h>

Stepper motor(200, 9, 10, 11, 12);

void setup() {
  rotateStepperBy(360);
}

void loop() {
  rotateStepperBy(90);
  delay(10);
}

void rotateStepperBy(float deg) {
  int steps = deg / 1.8;
  motor.step(steps);
}
```

Does motor.step complete and then the rest of the program resumes or does there need to be a longer delay for bigger degree measurements to allow the motor to finish stepping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does motor.step complete and then the rest of the program resumes..

Yes, `motor.step()` is [a blocking function](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StepperStep):

> This function is blocking; that is, it will wait until the motor has
>   finished moving to pass control to the next line in your sketch.

But you probably have to set the speed in `setup()`, for example `motor.setSpeed(30);`.

Looking at the [code for stepper](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/libraries/Stepper/src) it looks like `step_delay` stays undefined (or zero) until `setSpeed()` is called (i.e. it doesn't get a default value in the constructor..)

```
unsigned long step_delay; // delay between steps, in ms, based on speed
```

This value only changes in `setSpeed()`:

```
/*
 * Sets the speed in revs per minute
 */
void Stepper::setSpeed(long whatSpeed)
{
  this->step_delay = 60L * 1000L * 1000L / this->number_of_steps / whatSpeed;
}
```